# spanning tree on hypergraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Is there an algorithm to find a spanning tree (cost does not matter) on a hypergraph in both of the cases when it's uniform or non-uniform; assuming a spanning tree exists on the hypergraph?

Will Kruskal's Algorithm extend here too?

Comment: How are you defining "tree" here for a hypergraph? linear tree, or some other structure?

Comment: Linear tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

Deciding if a $k$-uniform hypergraph has a linear spanning tree is NP-complete for all $k\geq 3$. Of course one could still write a slow brute force algorithm to do this.

Unfortunately Kruskal's algorithm will not work usually. Take for example the $3$-uniform hypergraph on vertex set $[5]$ with edges $\{1,2,3\},\{3,4,5\},\{2,3,4\}$. If one attempts to naïvely run Kruskal's algorithm, and $\{2,3,4\}$ is the first edge chosen, then the algorithm will fail even though our hypergraph does has a spanning tree.